# Is there a Breakpoint Plugin for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins

#### Background

In some sufficiently large applications, you can spend more time figuring out how to drill down to the various layers than you do actually debugging: That's the case with a piece of software I work on now.  Layout/separation of concerns issues aside, it'd be nice to have a breakpoint plug-in that would allow you to load breakpoints depending on which Bugzilla/Jira/Fogbugz/SVN defect entry you're working off of.

#### Question

Do any plug-ins exist for Visual Studio that allow you to 'save' toggled breakpoints to a file, allowing you to load various breakpoints depending on what bug you're working on?

As an adjunct to that question; if there aren't any such plug-ins, can anyone point me to a 'good' (quite a subjective term, but in this case I mean explanatory and useful) resource on creating plug-ins for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this: "[Debugger Settings Visual Studio Add In– Easily Copy Breakpoints between Machines](https://www.wintellect.com/debugger-settings-visual-studio-add-in-easily-copy-breakpoints-between-machines/)"?

Comment: Looks interesting, have you used it?

Comment: No... but it comes from a respected author (and has source available).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Visual Studio 2010 (Professional) has added an "export breakpoints to file" function. (You can find it in the Breakpoints window.)

Answer (score 3):

I found this based on a recent Google search:

[Breakpoint Workspaces](http://bpworkspaces.codeplex.com/) by [Rick Schott](http://blog.devlpr.net/).

Comment: I have updated the installer, I will be releasing a much better version of this Add-In soon.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Breakpoint Analyzer for Visual Studio](http://intuitlabs.com/apps/breakpoint-analyzer-for-microsoft-visual-studio).

Comment: I'll take a look see; does it meet the criteria I laid out?

Comment: The link doesn't work for now. Does anybody have an updated link, or an offline copy of the add-in? (I need it for a project that has to be opened in VS 2008 only.)

Comment: **Noooo a broken link...** and no trace of it online anywhere now. If you have a copy of this add-in can you *please* host it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Break point analyzer is a really useful tool for debugging huge projects.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while searching the web for an answer. Since this question is pretty old, I thought I would contribute with an updated answer.

Nowadays, you can actually import and export breakpoints in Visual Studio from the Breakpoints window (`ctrl` + `alt` + `b`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293657(v=vs.100).aspx