# Visual Studio: Cycling through breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints

Is there a shortcut to cycle through my breakpoints? I often lose track of the breakpoints when debugging a project. When I finish working with one bug, I have to reset my breakpoints for a new bug that I am about to solve. It would be handy to have a keystroke that would allow me to cycle through the breakpoints and disable ones I don't need and keep the ones I need.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can always open the breakpoints window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) to cycle through them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can.

You can display a list of all breakpoints and jump to them using the breakpoint view (Debug / Windows / Breakpoints).

You may also be able to write a macro to do it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in way of doing this. However you might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653974/is-there-a-breakpoint-plugin-for-visual-studio). You can probably save the breakpoints for one bug and load it whenever you want it.